# I am trying to create a form with nav bar

Tags: html, css, forms, navigation, tags

I am trying to create a very **simple navigation bar** with **form**

i have done the `float:right` rule to the image and the `float:left;` to the navigation bar (header)

but it shows as inline together, i want the header to fill all the header (block)

here's the output image :

[image]

and here's the code :

```css
    body{
        background-color: beige;
    }
    ul{
        font-style:italic;
        font-weight:bold; 
        color:darkkhaki; 
        float:right;
    }  
    .front{
        float:right; 
        filter:grayscale(65%) blur(0.2px);  
        height:200px;
        width:300px;
    } 
    header{ 
        float:left;
        background-color:black;
        display:table; 
    } 
    .container{
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<header>   
    <div class="container">
        <nav> <img class="front" src="/D:/CSS.JPG" >
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="">Count Me In </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">Dont Count Me</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </nav> 
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i add background color of black for meaning , i wanted it to fill all the top "Bar" of the page

Comment: Do you want navgation bar to have image to right and links at left and with black as background color?

Comment: yes ! the image in the right and the links in the left ! but it sticks together for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!.. Happy to have you at StackOverflow.. Happy Designing!!

```css
body{
    background-color: beige;
}
ul{
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold; 
    color:darkkhaki; 
}  
li{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-right:5px;
}
li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.front{
    float: right; 
    filter:grayscale(65%) blur(0.2px);  
    height:35px;
    width:35px;
} 
header{ 
    float:left;
    background-color:black;
    width: 100%;
} 
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<header>   
    <div class="container">
        <nav> <img class="front" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-and-brands/512/21_Angular_logo_logos-512.png">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="">Count Me In </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">Dont Count Me</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </nav> 
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```